# How to tell the mysql table to retrieve the next matching record into my default table model

Tags: java, mysql, jtable, defaulttablemodel, data-retrieval

How do I tell my java program to retrieve the next matching record into my default table model.

Below is my home work so far.using `jTable` `tb1` and default table model `dtm` is compulsory for me.

```
 private void Show_My_LettersActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root");
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

            System.out.println("Creating statement...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * from LCI where SUB_ID = '" + SUB_ID_.getText() + "' AND L_DATE = '" + DATE.getText() + "'";
            ResultSet rs1, rs2, rs3, rs4, rs5, rs6, rs7;
            rs1=j.getData("select COUNT(*) from LCI");

            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
                DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tb1.getModel();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String L_ID_ = rs.getString("L_ID");
                    String L_DATE_ = rs.getString("L_DATE");
                    String heading = rs.getString("HEADING");
                    String sub_id = rs.getString("SUB_ID");

                    System.out.print("ID: " + L_ID_);
                    System.out.print(", Letter date: " + L_DATE_);
                    System.out.print(", Heading " + heading);
                    System.out.println(", Subject ID " + sub_id);


/* This gives the correct out put when debug is done.
    But the below code doesn't retrive the full out put. 
    It gives only the very first record matching with the user inputs*/


                    Vector v = new Vector();
                    Vector v1 = new Vector();
                    Vector v2 = new Vector();
                    Vector v3 = new Vector();

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Done");
                    dtm.getColumnName(1);
                    v.addElement(rs.getString(1));
                    dtm.addColumn(v);

                    dtm.getColumnName(3);
                    v1.addElement(rs.getString(3));
                    dtm.addColumn(v1);

                    dtm.getColumnName(10);
                    v2.addElement(rs.getString(10));
                    dtm.addColumn(v2);
                    // stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM   LCI WHERE  L_ID IN(SELECT (L_ID + 1)FROM   LCI  WHERE  L_DATE = '"+DATE.getText()+"'");

                  dtm.addRow(v3);
                 //stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM   LCI WHERE  L_ID IN(SELECT (L_ID '"+(+1)+"')FROM   LCI  WHERE  L_DATE = '"+DATE.getText()+"'");
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (stmt != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }// TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

Comment: Please don't use `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`. This hasn't been necessary any more since Java 6, which came out 12 years ago. Also, you're using try-with-resources for the `ResultSet`, so why not for the `Connection` and the `Statement`?

Comment: @SeverityOne. Thnak you. I'll look into it. But above code successfully retrieves the first matching record. What I need is to retrieve all the records that match with the condition into the     'jTable'     'tb1'

Comment: I'm sure it works. It's also 12 years out of date.